# What is a word that means detrimentally focused on a particular thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to write an essay, and I need to say that a holistic, global, comparative view is far more desirable than someone solely focusing on their own country.

I need a word that means focused on one thing to the point where it's detrimental. I feel like the word is on the tip of my tongue but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: 'Parochial' and 'insular' are given at the duplicate, Pietro.

Comment: In my mind the majority of the answers at the purported duplicate are *not* an answer to this question.  The only two words that come close are in a 1-upvote-answer far down the list with a comment saying this doesn’t answer the question.  The two words are: *preoccupation* and *fixation*.

Comment: If the OP thinks the question is not a duplicate they need to (1) follow the [guidelines for making single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and (2) explain why it's not a duplicate. I agree it may not be a duplicate, but we need elaboration of the question.